# The center of simple ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

We know that the center of the simple ring is either 0 or a field. I've searched for examples of simple rings with center 0 but couldn't find it. Can anyone help?
What example can we give of simple rings with a center 0?

Comment: The ring is unital?

Comment: No. If the ring is unital, the center of the ring contains at least the unit and is different from the empty. I thought this way it would be possible for the center of the ring to be nonzero.

Answer (score 1):

A famous example of Agata Smoktunowicz is an [example of a finitely generated simple nil-ring.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243045989_A_simple_nil_ring_exists) That ring has a trivial center:  Smoktunowicz, Agata
A simple nil ring exists. Comm. Algebra 30 (2002), no. 1, 27–59.

Indeed, if the ring $R$ has a non-zero central element $a$, then $aR$ is a right ideal (by definition). It is also left ideal because $tar=atr$. Since $R$ is simple, $aR=R$ (if $aR=0$, then the additive subgroup generated by $a$ is an ideal, hence $R$ is commutative). Then $ar=a$ for some $r\in R$, so $ar^k=a$ for every natural $k$. Since $R$ is nil, $r^k=0$ for some $k$, hence $a=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you. I looked at some more books. I guess we can give semisimple lie algebras as an example, right?

Comment: Semisimple Lie algebras are not associative rings and are not necessarily simple. If you drop associativity, then the statement that the center is 0 or a field is no longer true.

Comment: Yes, now I understand. Thanks again